# python3 object has no attriubute

Tags: python-3.x

I have a file called entities.py, which contains the following code:

```
class EntityClass: 
    entities = {}


def __init__(self, parent=None):
    .......


def show_all(self):
    ......
```

But then, when I run python 3 and type the command as follows:

```
>>> import entities
>>> ent = entities.EntityClass()
>>> ent.show_all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'EntityClass' object has no attribute 'show_all'
```

`show_all` should clearly be an attribute for EntityClass.
This of course worked perfectly in Python 2, and I'm assuming it's a Python 3 issue...
Is there a work around for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the code posted, it looks like your indentation levels are wrong, you have declared the show_all() method on the module, not the class.

`def_show_all(self):` Should be indented to the same level as `entities = {}`

```
class EntityClass: 
    entities ={}
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        .......

    def show_all(self):
        ......
```